# Where is the "heap"?

Tags: c, linux, memory

I just want to know where is (if present!) the Heap of my bash process (pid = 16457) in the result of `cat /proc/16457/maps`

```
0078a000-007a0000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1319336    /lib/ld-2.3.4.so
007a0000-007a1000 r--p 00015000 08:02 1319336    /lib/ld-2.3.4.so
007a1000-007a2000 rw-p 00016000 08:02 1319336    /lib/ld-2.3.4.so
007a9000-008cf000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1384495    /lib/tls/libc-2.3.4.so
008cf000-008d1000 r--p 00125000 08:02 1384495    /lib/tls/libc-2.3.4.so
008d1000-008d3000 rw-p 00127000 08:02 1384495    /lib/tls/libc-2.3.4.so
008d3000-008d5000 rw-p 008d3000 00:00 0
008fc000-008fe000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1319337    /lib/libdl-2.3.4.so
008fe000-008ff000 r--p 00001000 08:02 1319337    /lib/libdl-2.3.4.so
008ff000-00900000 rw-p 00002000 08:02 1319337    /lib/libdl-2.3.4.so
00b27000-00b2a000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 278109     /lib/libtermcap.so.2.0.8
00b2a000-00b2b000 rw-p 00002000 08:02 278109     /lib/libtermcap.so.2.0.8
08047000-080d8000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 902412     /bin/bash
080d8000-080de000 rw-p 00090000 08:02 902412     /bin/bash
080de000-080e3000 rw-p 080de000 00:00 0
09ceb000-09d25000 rw-p 09ceb000 00:00 0
b7d99000-b7d9b000 rw-p b7d99000 00:00 0
b7d9b000-b7da1000 r--s 00000000 08:02 130808     /usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
b7da1000-b7dd6000 r--s 00000000 08:02 869910     /var/db/nscd/passwd
b7dd6000-b7fd6000 r--p 00000000 08:02 101088     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
b7fd6000-b7fd8000 rw-p b7fd6000 00:00 0
bff07000-c0000000 rw-p bff07000 00:00 0
ffffe000-fffff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"The" heap most people refer to is this line:

```
080de000-080e3000 rw-p 080de000 00:00 0
```

i.e. it's the region of memory created and expandable by the `brk` syscall, immediately following the main program's `.data` and `.bss` segments.

One might also consider the following as part of the "heap":

```
09ceb000-09d25000 rw-p 09ceb000 00:00 0
```

It seems to be an anonymous mapping created by `mmap` to service a large `malloc` request. Most `malloc` implementations use `mmap` for large requests so they can `munmap` it on `free` and return the whole block of memory to the OS. It also makes `calloc` much faster since you're guaranteed to get per-zeroed pages this way.

Answer (score 1):

The heap is clearly marked as `[heap]` in current Linux versions. Your listing doesn't show it. Are you sure you didn't accidentally cut it out when copying it to your question?

On my shell:

```
~% grep '\[heap' /proc/$$/maps
00bca000-00d2e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
```

Answer (score 0):

The heap usually appears to be marked with [heap] when a malloc call is called; however, you'll notice that if you keep growing the heap with multiple lines of malloc() code that range will not grow; however, new blank line entries will be created.

Comment: That depends on the allocator, dlmalloc-derived ones tend to use `mmap()` for larger requests, and `brk()` for smaller requests, as mentioned by @R..